# Sharepoint site is not opening ? Http Error 500.19 - Internal server Error

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-config

When we are logged in SharePoint, site `Web.config` file its get updated with following line.

```
<SafeControl Assembly="MyCustomAssembly" Namespace="MyCustomNamespace" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
```

from web.config if we remove this line and i did `iisreset`.

Again this same line generating in web.config file.

so i am getting the same error again.

How to resolve this issue?

why its happening ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`<SafeControl>` must reside in the `<SafeControls>` element. See [SafeControls Element (Solution)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms413697.aspx).

Comment: yes but this tag was automatically added in inside of <system.serviceModel> tag. why this happening ?

Comment: This would be due to incorrect configuration of your (likely) `WebConfigModification` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

When you install the solution then it should registered safe control like below. I think u have to update ur manifest.xml file. or manully update the web.config.

```
<SafeControls>

        <SafeControl Assembly="MyCustomAssembly" Namespace="MyCustomNamespace" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />

  </SafeControls>
```

Comment: it was adding inside the <system.serviceModel>.If manually i updated the web.config also after few minutes again it was adding.

Comment: what u have in ur manifest.xml file?